# How to handle deprecated "Built in translators" in SQLite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite

It appears that type translation for the SQLite3 gem is deprecated. For example, this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'sqlite3'
dbh = SQLite3::Database.new('/tmp/my.db')
dbh.translator
```

produces these voluminous errors:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:75:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:75:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:77:in `register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:78:in `register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:86:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:86:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:86:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:86:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:86:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:86:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:86:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:92:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:92:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:92:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:92:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:92:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:97:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:97:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:97:in `block in register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb:106:in `register_default_translators' is calling `add_translator`.
Built in translators are deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.0
```

Is there a replacement for type translators? Am I just on my own in terms of doing type translation?

In particular, I want to translate `true` and `false` in Ruby into 1 and 0 in SQLite.

Comment: Did you ask the SQLite gem maintainers? They're the ones with intimate knowledge about a specific issue of a particular gem. https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/issues/1639

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually a benign series of warnings for debugging.

`ruby -w` sets a flag in SQLite3 that emits more verbose output.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'sqlite3'
dbh = SQLite3::Database.new('/tmp/my.db')
dbh.translator

# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/the_matrix.rb:51: warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/safe.rb:59: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/the_matrix.rb:54: warning: method redefined; discarding old exec
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/the_matrix.rb:60: warning: method redefined; discarding old exit!
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/the_matrix.rb:65: warning: method redefined; discarding old fork
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/the_matrix.rb:68: warning: method redefined; discarding old fork
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/the_matrix.rb:69: warning: method redefined; discarding old fork
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/seeing_is_believing-3.6.1/lib/seeing_is_believing/customize_pp.rb:2: warning: method redefined; discarding old pretty_print
# !> /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/pp.rb:396: warning: previous definition of pretty_print was here
....
```

Remove `-w` and try it:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby 
require 'sqlite3'
dbh = SQLite3::Database.new('/tmp/my.db')
dbh.translator
```

All warnings are gone.

As far as translating from `true`/`false` to `1`/`0` respectively, a simple hash makes it easy:

```
TRANSLATOR = {
  true => 1,
  false => 0
}

TRANSLATOR[true]  # => 1
TRANSLATOR[false] # => 0
```

I'd recommend not using the SQLite3 gem directly though. An ORM layer will make it very easy to write DBM-agnostic code making it easy to move from SQLite to PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc., without having to rewrite anything except for your data for the type of DBM, and using a YAML file to store the DSN information, reading it in and then populating the variables for the connection makes it even easier. Tweak the YAML file, restart the code and you're off and running.

Personally I like and recommend [Sequel](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/), but if you have Rails experience then Active Record is also a reasonable choice.

Comment: I keep warnings on always. Warnings are there for a reason, in this case to warn us that a feature will disappear. In fact, if I had my way, warnings would be the default and you'd have to take a proactive measure to turn them off.

OK, don't mean to sound snippy. You suggest a perfectly reasonable short-term solution, and I do believe that short-term solutions have their place in the world. But in this case, I need something longer term. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Warnings are fine, except when they're being used to trigger verbose diagnostics repeatedly. There should be a way to tell SQLite the level of warnings you want. I understand your point having written and supported big back-end systems for years, but a runaway log taking out a machine is irritating as can be, especially late at night. My development systems had verbose levels set, but our test set them to a less verbose setting, and production used critical errors. By the time code made it to production I'd hope we'd found the errors we put in.

Comment: I feel your pain. I've had warnings take down an entire server before I could figure out why I kept running out of disk space.